# Serenity appium full reset simulator only for one test

Tags: ios, maven, automation, appium, serenity-bdd

```
webdriver.driver = appium
appium.hub = http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
appium.platformName = iOS
appium.platformVersion = 9.3
appium.deviceName = iPhone 6 Plus
appium.app = "appPath"
appium.noReset = true
```

I have these serenity properties for appium in maven, I want to do a full reset only for one test and I dont have idea how to do, can someone help?

I tried with before to make some properties changes but no success :(

Comment: are you using testng ?

Comment: @ShekharSwami nope, simple junit

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to execute a command with full reset before test:

```
@Before
public void fullResetSimulator() {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xcrun simctl erase all");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.assertTrue("Simulator reset error: "+e.getMessage(),false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Before method will be executed before all Test.

Comment: @ShekharSwami yes, but for me is good because I have only one test in class.  Here is the class: [AppFirstStartTest.java](https://gist.github.com/Zbintiosul/4808467effc54409ce8ec3e100413b03)

Comment: Oh Great ! Accept your own answer :)